# Java lazy evaluation semantics

Tags: java, syntax, semantics, lazy-evaluation

What are the semantics of Java lazy evaluation? Do there exist triggers, stored together with assignment stores that append a trigger to the semantic stack of the trigger store if a program contains some syntax that symbolizes future lazy evaluation? and during execution, does program execution creates a new thread for that exact purpose or execution proceeds in the current thread? Also ... I would like to know what are possible syntaxes that can trigger lazy evaluation in Java?

Comment: Can you explain the context of this question?  I wasn't aware that Java had lazy-evaluation semantics.

Comment: 'lazy evaluation in Java' first links tell about it

Comment: You mean this one: http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/01/lazy-evaluation-in-java.html?  That doesn't say anything.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what about http://mindprod.com/jgloss/lazy.html ?

Comment: The only "lazy evaluation" at the language level is [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the `&&` and `||` operators, which was inherited from C.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth if I give you another link, you would say "these only lazy evaluations..". Think about LazyJ extension?

Comment: I wouldn't consider short-circuiting to be "lazy evaluation"; "lazy evaluation" usually has a more specific, different, meaning.  Whatever "LazyJ" is, it's not standard Java.

Comment: I can't tell how it is done at the circuit level, but I could tell it by semantics of the execution

Comment: In this context, "short-circuiting" is a convenient name; it's not describing anything literally at the circuit level.

Comment: you may edit my post for the changes you may find convenient to apply, I know i am bad at explaining things

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking about **[lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)** or **[short-circuiting operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**?

Comment: lazy evaluation, as it is written in the header

Comment: Then I believe your question has been answered!  Java doesn't have lazy evaluation.

Comment: owlstead had a point when he told about JVM, I am more concerned about the environment provided for semantic statements, the program may come from any language, but more important if we look at java byte code that contains some lazy excution

Comment: I feel that there is some confusion here. The JVM byte code does not perform lazy evaluation either. You can, of course, program lazy evaluation in byte code or java, but that does not make it a feature of either the VM or the Java language. The other languages that do provide lazy eval simply create the byte code to performs this feature.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, lazy evaluation is accomplished often by using object abstractions. In comparison, evaluation of code is passed about liberally in functional languages, making laziness a first-class feature.

In Java, if we want a value to be lazily updated, we wrap it's access in a method where we manage the complexity of evaluation in that method. Some of these constructs are referred to as beans: http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html.

Often one wants to create a data structure where all values are lazily obtained, e.g. a list where each element is lazily evaluated or a map where each value is lazily evaluated. To do this, we can subclass and override the get(), put(), and other applicable methods from relevant Java Collection classes. See [java cache hashmap expire daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407969/java-cache-hashmap-expire-daily) for an example of this strategy.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't have lazy evaluation.

Did you mean Scala?

Comment: Or any other functional language running on the JVM, I presume. Clojure comes to mind.

Comment: @owlstead if we are talking about JVM, then the byte code being executed in this environment can come from different languages(ones that support lazy executions and ones that not), so on this level, how environment does behave regarding the semantic statements with lazy execution?

Comment: @Mocialov: JVM bytecode is analagous to assembler; it doesn't have lazy-evaluation semantics.  It doesn't really have *any* semantics; each opcode is executed precisely as you ask for it (the JIT may do clever things, but they're implementation-dependent and hidden from the programmer).

Comment: no, but it does have an order of the statements and order change depending on the evaluation of the code

Comment: @Mocialov: The order of execution of opcodes is linear, until you reach a conditional branch-like opcode.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am not talking about micro architecture level, rather virtual machine. Not sure how it happens on that level, but as I understand if  Java would have any lazy execution, then it would be compilers job to translate program into right sequence of instructions. But here again, isn't it supposed to be known at run-time if the value is needed or not, in this case compiler cannot know if there is any on demand instruction is being pushed onto the execution stack

Comment: @Mocialov: The JVM is equivalent to micro-architecture; the bytecode is a sequence of instructions which the JVM follows in linear order.  Like I said, the JIT compiler is free to apply optimisations, but this is implementation-dependent, and nothing to do with the language.  You are correct, if Java *did* have lazy-evaluation semantics, then it would be the compiler's job to implement that by generating the right sequence of bytecode instructions.

Comment: @Mocialov Boris: I think that the other's explained enough about the lazy evaluation of other languages on the VM by now, if you need more explanation let me know

Comment: What @OliCharlesworth said. The Java language does not have lazy evaluation (i wouldn't call the short-circuiting operators lazy, really). The Java virtual machine does not have lazy evaluation. You can implement a lazy language on the JVM (even in Java), but the laziness comes from the implementation of that language, not from the JVM.